# Показ блока при открытии страницы и через какое-то время нахождения на сайте с помощью localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, localstorage

Есть небольшой плавающий блок на сайте, который закрывается только кликом на крестик.
разметка следующая:

```
<div> //обёртка
    <a class="close"> //кнопка закрытия
        <img alt=""src="">
    </a>
    <div> //содержимое баннера
       <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы этот блок показывался на какое-то время при открытии сайта, а дальше показывался, к примеру, через 5 минут нахождения на сайте.

Хочу использовать localStorage, чтобы записывать туда время когда блок был закрыт и показывать его снова по истечению времени, но не знаю как сделать.

Comment: В принципе, тут и LS не нужен. После закрытия окна запускайте интервал на 5 минут (5 * 60 * 1000) и выполняйте код показа окна по истечению. В варианте через LS вам придется постоянно проверять сколько времени прошло, т.е. придется создать интервал с маленькой задержкой, что не есть хорошо.

Comment: @MishaSaidov `localStorage` нужен, так как речь не о странице, а о сайте.

Comment: @Igor, упс, не подумал. В таком случае можно получить время через `new Date().getTime()`, записать его в LS, на каждой странице запускать интервал который будет считать разницу между текущим временем и записанным в LS, если оно превышает 5 минут (300000 мс.), открыть окно.

Comment: @MishaSaidov да, это, скорее всего, то, что нужно автору вопроса

Comment: @Misha Saidov, да, тоже к этому в итоге пришла. Спасибо